# _RequestVerificationToken secure false after ADFS login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, cookies, azure-web-app-service

i'm working on securing the cookies on my application, and am using the following to set the secure option to always.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
...         });
```

Now when I debug my site on azure and inspect the _RequestVerificationToken cookie secure is set to True.

However the problem is when I log in through active directory the _RequestVerificationToken secure is no longer true. I appreciate any advice you can offer.

Thanks

Comment: what's the value of  '_RequestVerificationToken'? AFAIK, this value was prevented the CRSF.

Comment: This is resolved now, it was only happening while debugging. When the project was built it was secure all the time. Thanks anyway

Comment: Nice. Congratulations.